# I am trying to make a diphthong counter, and i cannot seem to get it count all diphthongs present within the word

Tags: python, list, loops

```
word = input("Tell me the word you wish to check for diphthongs: ")
total = 0
diphthongs = ['ue', 'ie', 'ae', 'ee', 'oe', 'ui', 'ii', 'ai', 'ei', 'oi', 'ua', 'ia', 'aa', 'ea', 'oa', 'uo', 'io',
                  'ao', 'eo', 'oo', 'uu', 'iu', 'au', 'eu', 'ou']
stripped = word.strip('abcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz')
for letter in diphthongs:
    if letter in stripped:
        total += 1
print("There are", total, "diphthongs in the string")
```

**It can count 1 diphthong, but doesn't recognize the same diphthong twice, like c[ou]rth[ou]se, I also need to make it not recognize qu when searching for diphthongs**
Please and thank you?

I have tried splitting the diphthongs into regular vowels, I have tried range and len functions, but none seem to make it any easier, and the best results have come from what I have used so far.

Comment: One problem is illustrated by this line in your code: `for letter in diphthongs`. You are not iterating over letters. You are iterating over diphthongs; i,e., pairs of letters. You should rename `letter` for something more accurate such as `diphthong`. Sadly, the best answer retains your bad name for that variable.

Comment: What would be the desired result for an input of "ooe"? 1 or 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not the most efficient approach but I think you can use the [count](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/string/count) method to count the exact number of each diphthong instead of just checking if the substring exist in the a string which always match once as all substrings in `diphthongs` are iterated once

```
word = input("Tell me the word you wish to check for diphthongs: ")
total = 0
diphthongs = ['ue', 'ie', 'ae', 'ee', 'oe', 'ui', 'ii', 'ai', 'ei', 'oi', 'ua', 'ia', 'aa', 'ea', 'oa', 'uo', 'io',
                  'ao', 'eo', 'oo', 'uu', 'iu', 'au', 'eu', 'ou']

for diphthong in diphthongs:
    total += word.count(diphthong)
print("There are", total, "diphthongs in the string")
```

Comment: I would upvote your answer but you used the var name `letter` (from the O.P. question) which is not descriptive of the actual value. A var name such as `diphthong` would be better.

Comment: @KurtisRader Makes sense. I tried to minimize OP's code change but this might be better

Comment: You could also avoid giving it any name: `total = sum(map(word.count, diphthongs))`. (But your version might be clearer for the OP.)

Answer (score 1):

You're only checking if each diphthong is in the string once. You need to count the occurrences of each within the string. You could use the `str.count` method in a loop to accomplish this, or just use the `re` library.

```py
import re

diphthongs = [
  'ue', 'ie', 'ae', 'ee', 'oe', 'ui', 'ii', 
  'ai', 'ei', 'oi', 'ua', 'ia', 'aa', 'ea', 
  'oa', 'uo', 'io', 'ao', 'eo', 'oo', 'uu', 
  'iu', 'au', 'eu', 'ou'
]
r = re.compile('|'.join(diphthongs))
word = "courthouse"
diphtongs_found = r.findall(word)

print(f"There are {len(diphtongs_found)} diphthongs.")
```

*If* your goal is to find all two letter diphthongs in a word like `"courageous"` and count both `eo` and `ou` from `eou`, then you might use a list comprehension to generate all two letter substrings.

```
>>> diphthongs = [
...   'ue', 'ie', 'ae', 'ee', 'oe', 'ui', 'ii',
...   'ai', 'ei', 'oi', 'ua', 'ia', 'aa', 'ea',
...   'oa', 'uo', 'io', 'ao', 'eo', 'oo', 'uu',
...   'iu', 'au', 'eu', 'ou'
... ]
>>> word = "courageous"
>>> [
...   ss
...   for i in range(len(word) - 1)
...   for ss in (word[i : i + 2],)
... ]
['co', 'ou', 'ur', 'ra', 'ag', 'ge', 'eo', 'ou', 'us']
```

And then filter that list comprehension based on whether they occur in the `diphthongs` list.

```
>>> [
...   ss
...   for i in range(len(word) - 1)
...   for ss in (word[i : i+2],)
...   if ss in diphthongs
... ]
['ou', 'eo', 'ou']
```

Comment: I think this doesn't work? Consider "courageous", there are two instances of `'ou'` but this would only count the first one right?

Comment: Presumably both cannot be considered diphtongs at the same time in the same word, but yes, that is a corner case. In that case the approach using a loop and `str.count` would count them separately.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the built-in *sum()* function in conjunction with a generator as follows:

```
diphthongs = ['ue', 'ie', 'ae', 'ee', 'oe', 'ui', 'ii', 'ai', 'ei', 'oi', 'ua', 'ia', 'aa', 'ea', 'oa', 'uo', 'io',
                  'ao', 'eo', 'oo', 'uu', 'iu', 'au', 'eu', 'ou']

word = input("Enter the word to be checked: ")

print("There are", sum(word.count(d) for d in diphthongs), "diphthongs in the word")
```

There is a potential issue with this approach. Say the word is "oee". This would report 2 diphthongs. Should it perhaps just be 1?